# Obtener datos de una consulta SQL desde PHP

Tags: php, sql

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos que me devuelve esta función? (es la conexión con la base de datos).

```
function getData($sql)
{
    $data = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

    $error = mysqli_error($this->connection);

    if (empty($error)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                array_push($data, $row);
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception($error);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Ya que no puedo hacer un while fuera de la clase, he optado por eso. La información mostrada es la siguiente:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> string(1)...
```

Comment: Pues te devuelve un array, puedes acceder a los indices del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` es un array bidimensional, ya que cada `$row` que se lee en el `while` es en si también un array.

El método más sencillo, asumiendo que quieres sacar **todos** los datos, sería tener dos `for` o `foreach` uno anidado dentro del otro, e imprimirlos según te convenga

Un ejemplo con foreach sería el siguiente:

```
foreach ($data as $fila) {
    foreach ($fila as $muestra) {
        print $muestra;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la información!